# Is it possible to undo a file rename using Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, rename

Sometimes I want to rename a file that has quite a technical, complicated name by appending a date or some other information to it. Because the name can be complex, it can be problematic if the name is erased. When renaming a file using the "Rename..." option of a file's context menu in Nautilus, how can one undo the changes to a file name? The natural <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does nothing to revert the name, whether one is in the process of typing the new name or whether the name has been saved.

Comment: If you change your mind *while still in the process of renaming*, pressing Esc will revert any changes.

Comment: Just an observation that Ctrl+z works in my case (After the name is saved).  (Ubuntu 14.10, Nautilus 3.10.1). The Undo functionality even worked after I completely closed Nautilus and re-opened it, and without being inside the directory when the name change happened.

Comment: This is the typical case when I find that using command line (with history, copy and paste, TAB expansion, editing commands in the line...) is the best solution. Appending is just a matter of a well crafted `rename` command... Didn't add an answer because the question is clearly about nautilus...

Comment: @Jos ```Esc``` worked while in the process of renaming. Thanks.

@Dan Thanks for your suggestion. Under what appear to be the same conditions, this does not work for me.

@Rmano You're likely right. I happened to find the Nautilus behaviour unintuitive, so I mentioned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are still editing the file name, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the renaming without applying any changes. (You can still see the original name in the status bar in the lower right corner)

[image]

Once you confirmed it, you still can revert it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or through the
*Menu > Undo Renaming*.
This seems even to work after the Nautilus window was closed and reopened.

<sub>Screenshot failed with open menu. Sorry! :(</sub>

Comment: Great, ```Esc``` works. Thanks. For me, with Nautilus 3.10.1 in Ubuntu 14.10, ```Ctrl``` ```z``` does not work and there is no "Undo Renaming" option visible to me (in the Edit menu).

Comment: @d3pd But I have 14.10 and Nautilus 3.10.1 too... Strange. I just use XFCE instead of Unity, but that _should_ not make a difference (?) - But anyway, I prefer the other file managers like Nemo or Thunar to Nautilus, as it also has a few other bugs and less features.

Answer (score -1):

Simply confirm the file name change, then go to `Edit` → `Undo Renaming`. `ctrl+Z` also works but you first have to confirm the file name change.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. For me, with Nautilus 3.10.1 in Ubuntu 14.10, ```Ctrl``` ```z``` does not work and there is no "Undo Renaming" option visible to me in the Edit menu.